# Multitenant NHibernate application with with separate SQL Server schema for each tenant

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, multi-tenant

I am writing a new multi-tenant WCF RIA application. I plan to have a shared database with separate SQL Server schema for each tenant. I would like to use NHibernate for object-ralational mapping.

Configuration of SQL Server schema in mapping classes doesn't help because it is static and would need one set of mapping classes for each tenant.

Is it possible to dynamically configure ISession which SQL Server schema should be used for mapping objects to tables?

Comment: is there any link between each schema/client?

Comment: Yes, each client (tenant) would have a separate schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create a separate SessionFactory for each client, changing the `default_schema` property in the configuration accordingly.

Comment: I like the idea with a separate SessionFactory for each client very much. This way I can also also use a separate user name for each client and give it permissions only on objects from one schema.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no link between clients, then it maybe makes sense to have separate databases.

Not least, if client A says "please restore" you won't destroy other client's data.

Comment: I completely agree with you. The problem is that there will be many small clients. This leaves me with a lot of small databases to administer and pay for (I plan to use SQL Azure).

Comment: Ah, OK. Not my best idea then

Comment: I am going to start with one database, but will support spreading the clients over more databases if needed. Each database would contain data for a number of clients depending of their usage. With this setup it is possible for one database to contain data only for one client if they need it and want to pay extra.